# Animate just one linear gradient color stop in a circle

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am creating some circles where a certain portion of the circle is filled by a color by using a linear gradient. I am curious if it's possible to just animate one of the color stops in the circle. For example, if a circle is filled by the color red from 0 30% and the rest 30% 100% is filled by gray, is it possible to just create an animation effect on the 0 30% part that is filled with red. Since this is sort of like a progress bar, was hoping that it could appear as though the circle is being filled in by the color.  Here is the code:

```css
.page-wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  display:flex;
  flex-directon:row; 
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #001A5F;  
}

.circle-wrapper {
  max-width: 200px; 
  margin:40px; 
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
}
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 4px solid #a0c884; 
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #001A5F; 
  background-color: #a0c884;

  /*text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.7); */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}
.circle-text {
  font-size: 45px;
  /*letter-spacing: 4px; */
  font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.circle-text2 {
  color: #fff; 
  font-size:100px;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
  font-size:25px;
}

p {
  margin: 0; 
}

/* For illustration, no effect on click */
.example {
  background: linear-gradient(to top,
     #253715 0% 50%, #426e1f 50% 100%);
}

.example2 {
   background: linear-gradient(to top,
     #ce2029 0% 30%, #ececec 30% 100%);
}

.example3 {
   background: linear-gradient(to top,
     purple 0% 90%, #fff 90% 100%);
}

.circle-border {
   border: 4px solid #e14048; 
}

.circle-border2 {
   border: 4px solid #e14048; 
}

.circle-border2 {
   border: 4px solid #cd00cd; 
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper"> 
  


 <div class="circle-wrapper">
  <div class="circle filled example" data-fill="64">
    <p style="color:#fff" class="circle-text">50%</p>
      
</div>
  <h3>Class of 1960 </h3>
  <p> Raised: $500 </p>
  </p> Goal: $1000 </p> 
  
</div> 


<div class="circle-wrapper">
  <div class="circle circle-border filled example2" data-fill="64">
    <p class="circle-text">30%</p>
</div>
  <h3>Class of 1965 </h3>
  <p> Raised: $300 </p>
  </p> Goal: $1000 </p> 
  
</div> 


<div class="circle-wrapper">
  <div class="circle circle-border2 filled example3" data-fill="64">
    <p class="circle-text">90%</p>
</div>
  <h3>HCC </h3>
  <p> Raised: $900 </p>
  </p> Goal: $1000 </p> 
  
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Easiest way I can think of doing this would be to have the required colors already filled in, then have a white overlay filled in from the top (reverse progress bar), revealing the colors beneath as it shrinks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an @keyframes animation and break down the percentage by dividing the percentage by the number of steps you want to get the increment value to use in the @keyframes rule.

So in your example of ***30%***, you would create an animation for the CSS class `.example` which is *30%*. I chose to use percentages in increments of *5*, so *100* *divided by 5* gives me ***20*** steps. Now we divide ***30*** by ***20*** and this gives us ***1.5***. This is the amount we want to step up each ***5%*** increment in the *@keyframes rule*.

We begin adding the animation and giving it a name for the keyframes. In the example I use `fill`, I add a duration, `.7` seconds and add an `ease-in-out`. `animation: fill 0.7s ease-in-out;`

Then we also add the last keyframes styling so when the animation stops it shows the intended outcome, ***filled by 30%***.

```css
.example {
  animation: fill 0.7s ease-in-out;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 30%, #ececec 30% 100%);
}
```

Then we create the @keyframes rule... `@keyframes fill` with the animation name we used in the elements class, `.example`. Here we increment the `linear-gradient` by ***1.5%*** each step...

```css
  0% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 0%, #ececec 0% 100%);
  }
  5% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 1.5%, #ececec 1.5% 100%);
  }
  10% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 3%, #ececec 3% 100%);
  }
  /* stepping up by 5% in the @keyframes rule and adding 1.5% to both gradient
     settings each time until we reach 100% keyframe => 30% gradient fill */
```

```css
.circle-wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 4px solid #a0c884;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #001A5F;
  background-color: #a0c884;
  /*text-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.7); */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle-text {
  font-size: 45px;
  /*letter-spacing: 4px; */
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}


/* For illustration, no effect on click */

.example {
  animation: fill 0.7s ease-in-out;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 30%, #ececec 30% 100%);
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 0%, #ececec 0% 100%);
  }
  5% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 1.5%, #ececec 1.5% 100%);
  }
  10% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 3%, #ececec 3% 100%);
  }
  15% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 4.5%, #ececec 4.5% 100%);
  }
  20% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 6%, #ececec 6% 100%);
  }
  25% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 7.5%, #ececec 7.5% 100%);
  }
  30% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 9%, #ececec 9% 100%);
  }
  35% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 10.5%, #ececec 10.5% 100%);
  }
  40% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 12%, #ececec 12% 100%);
  }
  45% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 13.5%, #ececec 13.5% 100%);
  }
  50% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 15%, #ececec 15% 100%);
  }
  55% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 16.5%, #ececec 16.5% 100%);  
  }
  60% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 18%, #ececec 18% 100%);
  }
  65% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 19.5%, #ececec 19.5% 100%);
  }
  70% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 21%, #ececec 21% 100%);
  }
  75% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 22.5%, #ececec 22.5% 100%);
  }
  80% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 24%, #ececec 24% 100%);
  }
  85% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 25.5%, #ececec 25.5% 100%);
  }
  90% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 27%, #ececec 27% 100%);
  }
  95%{
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 28.5%, #ececec 28.5% 100%);
  }
  100% {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ce2029 0% 30%, #ececec 30% 100%);
  }
}

.circle-border {
  border: 4px solid #e14048;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="circle circle-border filled example" data-fill="64">
      <p class="circle-text">30%</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Class of 1965 </h3>
    <p> Raised: $300 </p>
    <p> Goal: $1000 </p>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple background and you can easily do it by animating `background-size`

```css
.page-wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  display: flex;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #001A5F;
}

.circle-wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 4px solid #a0c884;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #001A5F;
  background-color: #a0c884;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  animation:up 3s linear;
}

.circle-text {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
}

.circle-text2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}


/* For illustration, no effect on click */

.example {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#253715 0 0) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat
    #426e1f;
}

.example2 {
  background: 
     linear-gradient(#ce2029 0 0) bottom/100% 30% no-repeat
     #ececec;
}

.example3 {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(purple 0 0) bottom/100% 90% no-repeat
    #ececec;
}

.circle-border {
  border: 4px solid #e14048;
}

.circle-border2 {
  border: 4px solid #e14048;
}

.circle-border2 {
  border: 4px solid #cd00cd;
}

@keyframes up {
  from {
    background-size:100% 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="circle filled example" data-fill="64">
      <p style="color:#fff" class="circle-text">50%</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Class of 1960 </h3>
    <p> Raised: $500 </p>
    <p> Goal: $1000 </p>

  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="circle circle-border filled example2" data-fill="64">
      <p class="circle-text">30%</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Class of 1965 </h3>
    <p> Raised: $300 </p>
    <p> Goal: $1000 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle-wrapper">
    <div class="circle circle-border2 filled example3" data-fill="64">
      <p class="circle-text">90%</p>
    </div>
    <h3>HCC </h3>
    <p> Raised: $900 </p>
    <p> Goal: $1000 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! What does bottom/100% mean here? I am just trying to understand this part of the code bottom/100% 10% no repeat. Any explanation would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: @MK1030  `bottom/100% 10% no repeat` --> `[position]/[size] [repetition]` and size = `width height`